# Same Exact Online query in Invantive Control for Excel gives different result when executed with customer

Tags: sql, excel, exact-online, invantive-control

I have the following query to make a revenue report based on area groups from Exact Online:

```
select itemgroupcode 
,      itemgroupdescription 
,      code 
,      description 
,      country 
,      postcodegebied 
,      name 
,      financialyear 
,      financialperiod 
,      sum(quantity) 
       aantal 
,      sum(amountdc) 
       omzet  
,      sum(quantity2jaar) 
       aantal2014 
,      sum(omzet2jaar) 
       omzet2014 
,      sum(quantity1jaar) 
       aantal2015 
,      sum(omzet1jaar)
       omzet2015 
,      sum(quantityhuidigejaar) 
       aantal2016 
,      sum(omzethuidigejaar)
       omzet2016
from   ( select substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) 
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 0
                 then amountdc 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 * -1 
                 omzethuidigejaar 
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 1 
                 then amountdc 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 * -1 
                 omzet1jaar
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 2 
                 then amountdc 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 * -1  
                 omzet2jaar
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 0
                 then quantity 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 quantityhuidigejaar
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year (getdate()) - 1 
                 then quantity 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 quantity1jaar 
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 2 
                 then quantity 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 quantity2jaar 
         ,       case 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '10'
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '20' 
                 then '1000-1999'
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '20' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '30' 
                 then '2000-2999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '30' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '40' 
                 then '3000-3999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '40' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '50'
                 then '4000-4999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '50' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '60'
                 then '5000-5999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '60'
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '70' 
                 then '6000-6999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '70'
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '80'
                 then '7000-7999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '80' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) <= '89'
                 then '8000-8999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '90' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) <= '99'
                 then '9000-9999'
                 else 'unknown' 
                 end
                 postcodegebied
         ,       -1 * tle.amountdc
         ,       tle.financialperiod
         ,       tle.financialyear
         ,       act.country
         ,       act.name
         ,       itm.code
         ,       itm.description
         ,       tle.quantity
         ,       itm.itemgroupdescription
         ,       itm.itemgroupcode
         from    transactionlines tle
         join    exactonlinerest.crm.accounts act 
         on      act.code = tle.accountcode
         join    exactonlinerest.financial.glaccounts glt 
         on      glt.code = tle.glaccountcode
         --
         -- Type 110: grootboekrekening van het type omzet
         --
         and     glt.type = 110 
         join    exactonlinerest.logistics.items itm
         on      tle.itemcode = itm.code 
         --
         -- zodat er alleen transacties worden meegenomen die op een artikel geboekt zijn.
         --
         where   tle.itemcode is not null
       ) tle2
group 
by     itemgroupcode
,      itemgroupdescription 
,      code 
,      description 
,      country 
,      postcodegebied
,      name 
,      financialyear 
,      financialperiod
order 
by     itemgroupcode 
,      financialyear 
,      itemgroupdescription 
,      code 
,      description 
,      country 
,      postcodegebied
,      name 
,      financialperiod
```

When executing this query on the machine of a customer I expect the same result. But the outcome is different. Each amount and quantity is multiplied by a factor eight depending on whether the query is run as Exact Online user 'ME@acme.com' or 'OTHERPERSON@acme.com'.

How can this be occuring and how would I be able to fix this?

Comment: How many divisions are you querying? Could it be that that multiplies the number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query misses a number of optimizations and does not include the full join conditions.

Please note that the unique natural or business key of for instance an item is both division (company) and the item code, so always include both in the join. When you forget to include division where applicable, you multiply the number of rows if you use identical (copies) divisions. With non-copies you get varying results.

Giving that you get 8 times as much and the presence of 3 joins, I guess you are running sometimes with 2 identical/copy divisions selected in Exact Online and that causes power(2, 3) = 8 times as high values.

Also, you are retrieving many general ledger transaction lines that you do not use in the aggregation like those of 3 years old or older. It is better to exclude those early with a clause like `financialyear >= ...`.

The correct query should be something like:

```
select itemgroupcode 
,      itemgroupdescription 
,      code 
,      description 
,      country 
,      postcodegebied 
,      name 
,      financialyear 
,      financialperiod 
,      sum(quantity) 
       aantal 
,      sum(amountdc) 
       omzet  
,      sum(quantity2jaar) 
       aantal2014 
,      sum(omzet2jaar) 
       omzet2014 
,      sum(quantity1jaar) 
       aantal2015 
,      sum(omzet1jaar)
       omzet2015 
,      sum(quantityhuidigejaar) 
       aantal2016 
,      sum(omzethuidigejaar)
       omzet2016
from   ( select substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) 
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 0
                 then amountdc 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 * -1 
                 omzethuidigejaar 
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 1 
                 then amountdc 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 * -1 
                 omzet1jaar
         ,       case 
                 when financialyear = year(getdate()) - 2 
                 then amountdc 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 * -1  
                 omzet2jaar
         ,       case 
                 when tle.financialyear = year(getdate()) - 0
                 then tle.quantity 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 quantityhuidigejaar
         ,       case 
                 when tle.financialyear = year (getdate()) - 1 
                 then tle.quantity 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 quantity1jaar 
         ,       case 
                 when tle.financialyear = year(getdate()) - 2 
                 then tle.quantity 
                 else 0 
                 end
                 quantity2jaar 
         ,       case 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '10'
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '20' 
                 then '1000-1999'
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '20' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '30' 
                 then '2000-2999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '30' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '40' 
                 then '3000-3999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '40' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '50'
                 then '4000-4999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '50' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '60'
                 then '5000-5999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '60'
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '70' 
                 then '6000-6999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '70'
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) < '80'
                 then '7000-7999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '80' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) <= '89'
                 then '8000-8999' 
                 when substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) >= '90' 
                      and substr(act.postcode, 1, 2) <= '99'
                 then '9000-9999'
                 else 'unknown' 
                 end
                 postcodegebied
         ,       -1 * tle.amountdc
         ,       tle.financialperiod
         ,       tle.financialyear
         ,       act.country
         ,       act.name
         ,       itm.code
         ,       itm.description
         ,       tle.quantity
         ,       itm.itemgroupdescription
         ,       itm.itemgroupcode
         from    transactionlines tle
         join    exactonlinerest..accounts act 
         on      act.code = tle.accountcode
         and     act.division = tle.division
         join    exactonlinerest..glaccounts glt 
         on      glt.code = tle.glaccountcode
         --
         -- Type 110: GL Account of type Revenue.
         --
         and     glt.type     = 110 
         and     glt.division = tle.division
         join    exactonlinerest.logistics.items itm
         on      itm.code     = tle.itemcode
         and     itm.division = tle.division
         --
         -- Only transaction lines with an item.
         --
         where   tle.itemcode is not null
         --
         -- Only journal for revenues.
         --
         and     tle.journalcode = '70'
         --
         -- Optimization: not interested in older transactions than 2 years.
         --
         and     tle.financialyear >= year(getdate()) - 2
       ) tle2
group 
by     itemgroupcode
,      itemgroupdescription 
,      code 
,      description 
,      country 
,      postcodegebied
,      name 
,      financialyear 
,      financialperiod
order 
by     itemgroupcode 
,      financialyear 
,      itemgroupdescription 
,      code 
,      description 
,      country 
,      postcodegebied
,      name 
,      financialperiod
```